# Avoid value error in dataframe from for loop list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, valueerror

I’m using the extract_msg module to read thousands of emails from which I extract things like the sender, receiver, date and body.

I loop over my list of .msg files and save the relevant content to different lists. When I try to add the lists to a dataframe, I get an value error.

I turns out that the length of the body list is 3429 and all other lists are 3431 items long. It looks like perhabs 2 of the e-mails are empty resulting in this problem.

I can create a pd.Series of the body list, but the problem is that this simply adds to empty records at the end of the list, instead of on the spot where the list is actually empty.

What can I add to my for loop to either replace empty records with some sort of string or skip them completely?

This is how I extract the different components from the e-mails

```
#run for loop
for filename in f:
    try:
        msg = extract_msg.Message(filename)
        paths.append(filename)
        senders.append(msg.sender)
        recipients.append(msg.to)
        dates.append(msg.date)
        subjects.append(msg.subject)
        body.append(msg.body)
```

and this is how I add them to a df

```
#create df
df= pd.DataFrame({'path':paths})
df['map'] = df['path'].str.split('\\').str[4]
df['bestand'] = df['path'].str.split('\\').str[-1]
df ['afzender']  = senders
df [ 'ontvanger'] = recipients
df['datum'] = dates
df['onderwerp'] = subjects
df ['tekst'] = body
```

UPDATE:
I tried printing the length of each item and got a Nonetype error. I therefore assume that my problematic emails contain no content. I have checked this by printing a certain string (if msg.body is NONE: print ("error").

I figured I could solve my problem by including the following if-else statement, but the length of my body list remains 2 items too short.

```
 if msg.body is None:
            body.append("empty")
        else:
            body.append(msg.body)
```

Comment: Try to replace `if body_item == '':` with `if body_item == None:`

Comment: @frankfalse I tried printing (len(body_item)) in the for loop and this indeed gives a nonetype error. I have tried  adding ``` if msg.body == None:
            body.append('empty')
        else:
            body.append(msg.body) ```   But this does not change the length of the list that is produced :(

Comment: `body.append(msg.body if msg.body else "empty")`